# system.NullReferenceException in MFC application

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++, mfc, nullreferenceexception

I have developed one SDI application using MFC/C++.

**The scenario is:**

I have tested this application in PCs having `Win xp, 7, 8, 8.1`.

It was working fine in PC environment having `.NET Framework and some redistributables`.

It was working fine on all tested environments.

But not it is giving error message as `System.NullreferenceException` while running on client PC.

**Problem**

I am not able to trace the problem that where this would be happened?

Can any one point me out some way to resolve this problem?

Please forgive me if This is not a valid question.

Any type of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's time to dig out those pdb files!

Comment: @Bathsheba Can you please explain?

Comment: They are Program Database Files: and get built at the same time as the binaries. Have a google for them. There is a learning curve here.